# Unwanted white background color

Tags: html, css

On https://andergene.com/pricing.html I am trying to figure out why the "Pay Now" button goes white when hovered over. I have combed through the CSS, done all sorts of testing and tinkering in Firebug and cannot locate where that is coming from. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what tinkering you did but simply right click > Force Element State > hover (Chrome) will show you exactly where it is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition in your CSS causing that. This are in line `1597` of `style.css` file.

```
.agency-pro-blue .archive-pagination li a:hover, .agency-pro-blue .archive-pagination li.active a, .agency-pro-blue a.button:hover, .agency-pro-blue button:hover, .agency-pro-blue input[type="button"]:hover, .agency-pro-blue input[type="reset"]:hover, .agency-pro-blue input[type="submit"]:hover, body.agency-pro-blue {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

To solve change to:

```
.agency-pro-blue .archive-pagination li a:hover, .agency-pro-blue .archive-pagination li.active a, .agency-pro-blue a.button:hover, .agency-pro-blue button:hover, .agency-pro-blue input[type="button"]:hover, .agency-pro-blue input[type="reset"]:hover, body.agency-pro-blue {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think now that the problem was that I was using the Firefox inspector tools that are like Firebug but not exactly like them and don't show hover states as readily as Firebug does. But then in my OP I referred to Firefox inspector tools as "Firebug" but now I see they are not exactly the same thing. I was also having a different issue in Chrome that was obscuring the inspection.

Comment: Firefox has this funtionality too natively !!, right click on any element at page, then right click in HTML that show the inspector, then click on :hover. This way you can fin the styles.

Comment: @ChristianZiebarth There is a check box in the top left corner. Uncheck it and the screen won't resize

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. lmgonzales, I tried to vote up your answer but it said I can't vote up an answer even on my own question because I don't have a reputation of 15 yet. And the reason I don't have a reputation of 15 yet is that I had to start a new Stack Overflow account because I found out last night that it will no longer allow me to log in with my Yahoo ID. So, thanks, Stack Overflow.